# Problema con php: expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php, mysql

PHP me marca un error al momento de intentar un login, me marca este error:

> ```
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE), expecting ',' or ';' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/webagropac/conexion.php on line 10
> ```

Éste es el código:

```
<?php

class conexion {
  private $conexion;
  private $server = "localhost";
  private $usuario = "root";
  private $pass = "aassdd";
  private $db = "Agropacdb;"

  private $user; /*Aqui marca el error*/
  private $password; /*Aqui marca el error*/

  public function_construct() {
  $this->conexion = new mysqli($this->server, $this->usuario, $this->pass, $this->db);

  if($this->conexion->connect_errno){

    die("Fallo al tratar de conectar con MySQL: (". $this->conexion->connect_errno.")");

   }

  }

  public function cerrar() {
    $this->conexion->close();
  }

  public function login($usuario, $pass) {

    $this->user = $usuario;
    $this->password = $pass;

    $query = "SELECT id_u, nombre_u, apellido_u, alt_u, pass_u From Usuarios WHERE alt_u = '".$this->user."' and pass_u = '".$this->password."' ";

    $consulta = $this->conexion->query($query);

    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){

        session_start();

        $_session['id'] = [$id_u];
        $_session['nom'] = [$nombre_u];
        $_session['ape'] = [$apellido_u];

        echo "Has iniciado sesion";

        echo $_session['id'];
        echo $_session['nom'];
        echo $_session['ape'];

    } else {

      echo "Usuario o contrasena incorrectos";
    }
  }

}

 ?>
```

La línea 10 es:

```
private $db = "Agropacdb;"
```

Comment: Mariano ya soluciono el problema `private $db = "Agropacdb";` el error estaba en `;` estaba demás el punto y coma.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es un error tipográfico y no una pregunta de código, sin valor para futuros lectores.

Comment: como hago eso? Y disculpen por ese detalle.

Comment: @GuillermoNavarro Ya aceptaste una respuesta. No hay nada más que te corresponda hacer en cuanto a esta pregunta. Me alegro que te haya ayudado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta línea:

```
private $db = "Agropacdb;"
                       ^^^^
```

Debería ser:

```
private $db = "Agropacdb";
```

---

Como verás, incluiste el `;` dentro de las comillas, por lo que lo toma como parte del texto, y no separa instrucciones.